# Spring Boot restful resource security - Authentication not firing

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm having issues in securing restful resources using Spring Boot 1.1.7.  I have created a SecurityConfiguration with a custom AuthenticationProvider.

The SecurityConfiguration and AuthenticationProvider beans are being loaded, but  my custom 'authenticate' method is never being fired.  I've reviewed most of the tutorials but cannot restrict access to any url using the custom authentication.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    private @Autowired CustomAuthenticationProvider provider;

    /**
     * Configure global.
     *
     * @param auth the auth
     * @throws Exception the exception
     */
//  @Autowired
//  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
//              auth.authenticationProvider(this.provider);
//  }
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        log.warn("Configure AuthMgrBuilder");
        auth.authenticationProvider(this.provider);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity)
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.warn("Configure http");
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the configure(HttpSecurity http) method as follows, and it now authenticates through the Authentication provider using basic http security.  Not sure this is the best approach though.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.warn("Configure http");
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
//          .antMatchers("/**")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic();
    }
```

Comment: That seems perfectly sensible to me. If you want to collect credentials in a different way you need to say what that is (Spring isn't going to be able to guess).